# How to tell maven to compile a project as an aspectj project

Tags: java, maven, aspectj

My project:

`src/main/aspects`:

```
com
 |---badmitrii
        |---Trace.aj
```

`src/main/java`:

```
com
 |---badmitrii
        |---App.java
```

I wrote the following pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.badmitrii</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-test</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>aspectj-test</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>com.badmitrii</groupId>
                            <artifactId>aspectj-test</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.badmitrii.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.badmitrii.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

But the jar is still being compiled as a java-project and when I run it with `java -jar <jar-name>` I didn't get the desirable `aspectJ` result.

How to tell maven to compile the jar with respect to aspects?

UPD:

App.java:

package com.badmitrii;

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        App  a = new App ();
        a.m();
    }

    public void m(){
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

Trace.aj:

```
package com.badmitrii.aspects;

public aspect Trace {
    pointcut publicMethodExecuted(): execution(public !static * *(..));

    after(): publicMethodExecuted() {
        System.out.printf("Enters on method: %s. \n", thisJoinPoint.getSignature());

        Object[] arguments = thisJoinPoint.getArgs();
        for (int i =0; i < arguments.length; i++){
            Object argument = arguments[i];
            if (argument != null){
                System.out.printf("With argument of type %s and value %s. \n", argument.getClass().toString(), argument);
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("Exits method: %s. \n", thisJoinPoint.getSignature());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try configuring the plugin as [the documentation](http://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/examples/libraryJars.html) describes:

> In order to apply already compiled aspects to your own sources you
>   need do setup all the JAR files you would like to weave in the plugin
>   configuration as shown below.

which would be

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>com.badmitrii</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectj-test</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
            </configuration>
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <goals>
                 <goal>compile</goal>
               </goals>
             </execution>
           </executions>
        </plugin>
```

---

Updated after code post:

However, yours is not a pre-compiled aspect. So you don't need the configuration of aspectLibraries, you only need the goal:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <goals>
                 <goal>compile</goal>
               </goals>
             </execution>
           </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Also, you should add the version of the maven-plugin:

```
<artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.7</version>
```

This will compile your aspect if you comment out the printf lines (they are not written correctly, and they are beyond the scope of this question).
You may test it with a System.out.println("I am inside the aspect") inside the aspect to see it works.

Like:

```
package com.badmitrii.aspects;

public aspect Trace {
    pointcut publicMethodExecuted(): execution(public !static * *(..));

    after(): publicMethodExecuted() {
//        System.out.printf("Enters on method: %s. \n", thisJoinPoint.getSignature());
        System.out.println("inside the aspect - after");
        Object[] arguments = thisJoinPoint.getArgs();
        for (int i =0; i < arguments.length; i++){
            Object argument = arguments[i];
            if (argument != null){
//                System.out.printf("With argument of type %s and value %s. \n", argument.getClass().toString(), argument);
            }
        }
//        System.out.printf("Exits method: %s. \n", thisJoinPoint.getSignature());
    }
}
```

Comment: I got the pom-error Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration

Comment: Standard usage doesn't specifcy the use of aspectLibraries (http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/usage.html). Have you tried simply running it without that configuration?

Comment: Well, no. Beacause I cann perfrom maven install.

Comment: The error was __The artifact com.badmitrii:aspectj-test referenced in aspectj plugin as an aspect library, is not found the project dependencies__

Comment: The documention link i provided in the answer does specify "Note: The artifacts you reference must exist as dependencies in your project."

Comment: However, by specifing an aspectLibrary (i.e. com.badmitrii : aspectj-test) you are telling the plugin you have an already compiled aspect JAR. But you are trying to compile it (being your main project). So as i've said, try without it

Comment: If I try without it, the aspect is not compiled. __D:\aspectJ\aspectj-test\src\main\aspect\com\badmitrii\Trace.aj:16:0::0 The method printf(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, Signature)__

Comment: Please post your Trace and App code for further help. That error message does not tell me much

Comment: I have updated the answer with the pom config that compiles your aspect. The problem is your aspect, it's incorrect. Comment out the lines with printf and write something like pritln("Works").

Comment: For the Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle error, if you are using eclipse, one solution is to discover the m2e eclipse connector for the plugin. Use quick-fix on the error in pom.xml and select "Discover new connectors"